# ReplaceAll with escape character not working as expected Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in which I want to replace all with specified word the below solution works fine however when we use dot to replace with multiple dots it replaces everything with dot.

```js
const textToReplace = 'sample';
const string = 'This is sample string.'
const regExp = new RegExp(textToReplace, 'g');
const result = string.replaceAll(regExp, 'noSample');
console.log(result)
// output: This is noSample string.
```

The above example works fine, however if we replace dot with multiple dots the output is weird it replace everything with dots.

```js
const textToReplace = '.';
const string = 'This is sample string.'
const regExp = new RegExp(textToReplace, 'g');
const result = string.replaceAll(regExp, '...');
console.log(result)
// output: ..................................................................
```

To fix the dot I added escape `\\` character in regex which works fine in dot case.

```js
const textToReplace = '.';
const string = 'This is sample string.'
const regExp = new RegExp(`\\${textToReplace}`, 'g');
const result = string.replaceAll(regExp, '...');
console.log(result)
// output: This is sample string...
```

BUT it does not work for other strings to replace.

```js
const textToReplace = 'sample';
const string = 'This is sample string.'
const regExp = new RegExp(`\\${textToReplace}`, 'g');
const result = string.replaceAll(regExp, 'noSample');
console.log(result)
// output: This is sample string. [no impace it does not replace sampel with noSample]
```

Any regex expert to fine tune the regex to make it functional for both word or dot.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's normal, because a dot in regex is equivalent to any char. and when you write `\\sample`, it matches a blank char (`space, or newline or tab`) followed by `ample`, that doesn't appear in your stirng

Comment: You don't need to create a regular expression at all simply to replace all instances of a specific substring in text with something else - just use `stringValue.replaceAll( textToReplace, replacementText)` directly. (MDN documentation: [String.prototype.replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)).